# How to convert multiple html tables to excel with multiple sheets in one workbook in Angular 6?

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have 6 tables in html i need to export these 6 tables to excel with each table in one sheet (Six sheets in one workbook). How can i achieve this in Angular 6 ?

Comment: Someone please answer to this

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using the [`xlsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) npm module which supports the CSF (Common Spreadsheet Format) that lets you specify sheet based pagination as you require, and can generate an xlsx file.

You can further use the [`file-saver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) module to save data and trigger a download on the browser using the new Streams API.

Comment: How to write functionality of button click for export in typescript with multiple tables? Logic to trigger export function in typescript ?

Comment: can you give me an example ?